# How to fix docker container exiting with code 6?

Tags: docker, meteor, docker-compose

## Context

I am running a dockerized ubuntu for a Meteor (js) application with docker-compose file on my personnal computer. It is attached to a mongo DB container. And a nginx proxy container is running to make my development url secured with ssl (https).

#### Docker Images

- ubuntu : ubuntu:18.04
- nginx proxy : jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
- mongo : mongo:latest
- Plus my own meteor app locally.

#### Other

- Meteor version : 1.8.1
- Docker version : 18.09.3, build 774a1f4
- Docker Compose version : 1.23.2, build 1110ad01

## Problem

Since I stopped my containers with docker-compose down, when I restart them, my webapp container exits (with exit code 6) all the time. I didn't change the docker-compose files since my previous `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml --verbose up`

#### Error displayed by `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml --verbose up`

```
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('26d90365fe9a4b0c0eb24cb2c040aa43cf8ec207764f350b6273ee7362d9fe0e')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait <- ('26d90365fe9a4b0c0eb24cb2c040aa43cf8ec207764f350b6273ee7362d9fe0e')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/26d90365fe9a4b0c0eb24cb2c040aa43cf8ec207764f350b6273ee7362d9fe0e/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/containers/26d90365fe9a4b0c0eb24cb2c040aa43cf8ec207764f350b6273ee7362d9fe0e/wait HTTP/1.1" 200 30
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait -> {'Error': None, 'StatusCode': 6}
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': [],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['meteor'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': None,
            'Env': ['ENV_APP_SERVER_USERNAME=app',
...webappContainer exited with code 6
```

#### Result of `docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                      NAMES
26d90365fe9a        xxxxxxxxxx_webapp            "meteor"                 23 minutes ago      Exited (6) 13 seconds ago                                              webappContainer
4073bbfe37cf        mongo                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   39 minutes ago      Up 14 seconds               0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                   mongoDBContainer
201f0a99d1cf        jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine   "/app/docker-entrypo…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                  0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   nginx-proxy_nginx-proxy_1
```

#### Result of `docker logs <container_id>`

** none **

> *How ? The container will not even start. When I do docker run  it works..*

## Source files

- docker-compose.dev.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    container_name: webappContainer
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: mysite.local
      VIRTUAL_PORT: ${PORT}
    build:
      context: ${CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: ${DOCKERFILE}...
    volumes:
      - ${VOLUME}:/usr/src/app
    expose:
      - ${PORT}
    networks:
      - dbAppConnector
      - default
    depends_on:
    - mongodb
  mongodb:...
    container_name: ${MONGO_CONTAINER_NAME}
    image: mongo
    restartmongodb: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
    - "${MONGO_PORT}:${MONGO_PORT}"..
    networks:
      dbAppConnector:
    volumes:
    - mongo_volume:/data/db
    - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
volumes:
  mongo_volume:
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
  dbAppConnector:
```

> Note that when i do `docker-compose config` every .env variables are correctly displayed.

- Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Set environment dir & copy files
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Make host.docker.internal accessible from outside the container (dev only)
# RUN ip -4 route list match 0/0 | awk '{print $3 "host.docker.internal"}' >> /etc/hosts

# Add user to run localy (dev only) the app
RUN addgroup meteoruser &&  useradd -rm -d /home/moff -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 1000 meteoruser

# Update distribution
RUN apt-get update -q && apt-get clean \
  # Install curl
  && apt-get install curl -y \
  # Install Meteor
  && (curl https://install.meteor.com | sh) \
  # Install node js
  && cd /usr/src/app \
  # replace vx.x.x by meteor node -e 'console.log("I am Node.js %s!", process.version);' output from my project folder.
  && bash -c 'curl "https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.15.1/node-v8.15.1-linux-x64.tar.gz" > /usr/src/app/required-node-linux-x64.tar.gz' \
  && cd /usr/local && tar --strip-components 1 -xzf /usr/src/app/required-node-linux-x64.tar.gz \
  && rm /usr/src/app/required-node-linux-x64.tar.gz \
  && cd /usr/src/app \
  && npm install

RUN cd /usr/src/app && chown -Rh meteoruser .meteor/local
EXPOSE 80
ENV PORT 80
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

USER meteoruser
CMD ["meteor"]
```

## What I currently tried to fix the problem

- I Stopped and removed all containers, removed all images, removed all networks, and rebuild everything.
- I Checked my internet access (average ping: ~35ms).
- I Tried different version of "Meteor js" (1.8.1, latest, 1.8.0.2) with the flag `?release=1.8.0.2` in the Dockerfile.dev part where I do `&& (curl https://install.meteor.com | sh) \`.
- I Tried to find some documentation about code 6 when a container is exiting but found nothing relevant.
- It tried to look at logs but none were available for the exited app container xxxxxx_webapp : result empty.
- I tried to start separately the xxxxxx_webapp container and had a weird result with `docker run xxxxxxx_webapp`.

```
This is your first time using Meteor!
Installing a Meteor distribution in your home directory.
Downloading Meteor distribution
```

It took 2+ minutes to finally show :

```
Retrying download in 5 seconds …
Retrying download in 5 seconds …
Retrying download in 5 seconds …
Retrying download in 5 seconds …

[[[[[ /usr/src/app ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
```

And so the container is running without exiting with the separate `docker run` command..

> Reminder: everything was working fine for 4+ weeks, then suddenly I suspect my new internet connection being too slow (I moved from my parents house 1 week ago).

**Could you guys please give some advises ? Is there any additional information I could provide to help you understand what I am missing ?** Thanks in advance!

### Edit

Other tries to make things work:

- I removed and reinstall everything from docker.
- I tried a previous version of the app, 3 weeks ago that was fully working.
- I Tried everything except using another wi-fi. Could this works? I don't think so but it there is always a hope.

Comment: Can you trim down your code some?  If there are details like the network setup that don’t make any difference to the question, just remove them.

Comment: You’re also using a Docker bind mount to replace the application code in your image.  This isn’t something you’d ever do in a production setup (the image should be self-contained) and I’d suggest trying to avoid it in a development setup too; use native host tools when they make sense.  The contents of the `${VOLUME}` directory are probably essential to reproduce this.

Comment: @DavidMaze The bind mount is only for dev purposes so that I can enjoy hot code reload in the browser, but of course, in production it is self container image! Ok i'll trim it down thanks for reply :)

Comment: Since you're mounting your source code in, and the container is running with the command  "meteor", did you change any source code files in between runs? Can we see the full compose file?

Comment: @DaveS I edited the docker-compose file content.  I think I will try to get the previous version of the app and run it to see if there is still that problem. I'll let you know if it worked :)

Comment: Ok .. Very bad news, I cloned my previous app version (fully working one) and did a `docker-compose -f  docker-compose.dev.yml up -d --build`, it went ok, but once I `docker ps` I see my webapp container is still exiting with code 6 .. Could this be my very slow internet causing that ?? It makes no sense.. but it is the only parameter that changed since my last update.. The worst is that I can run the container separately (not from docker-compose) and it downloads Meteor distribution very slowly but it is working ..

Comment: Next step : removing everything linked to Docker (ce) except the project. And reinstalling. Then I will re try.

Comment: Day 003 : Completely removed containers, images, networks, docker itself and all about docker, then reinstalled everything and re-download my project and ran it did change nothing. Next step: trying to lauch it from another wi-fi. I completely struggle on that problem, it seems everything on the project is up to date, docker too, my computer too, running the app container alone is working because there is like no timeout, in docker-compose it exits pretty fastly, like 5 secondes maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION

I uninstalled e-v-e-r-y-t-h-i-n-g from docker on my computer like this :

> Warning : Be aware that with this procedure you will lose your configuration, images, and containers.

- First I removed unused data from the 'system' with :

```
sudo docker system prune
```

- Then, removed all networks and volumes :

```
sudo docker volume prune
sudo docker network prune
```

- Then, a complete uninstall of docker was necessary :

```
apt-get remove --purge docker*
```

- then I had to remove the docker containers and images :

```
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

- then, remove config files, ..

```
rm -rf /etc/docker
rm /etc/systemd/system/docker.service
rm /etc/init/d/docker
```

- Then removed osbolete and orphan packages:

```
apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean
```

- Then update and upgrade existing packages

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Finally reinstalled docker and docker-compose from :

- Docker install procedure : https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04/
- Docker-compose install procedure : https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-use-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-18-04/

And at the and I redownloaded from git my project, reinstalled it with `docker-compose up -d`  :)

So, I believe this was a config problem with docker. Unfortunately I never found a clear answer on that "exit code 6" ..

*Feel free to share your solution if you ever encounter the same "exit code 6" problem guys.*

Answer (score 1):

Though I never found out what exit code 6 is either, I did find it's cause in my setup.
Turns out my environment was invalid because I had accidentally set it to a branch that didn't exist.

docker-compose --verbose up set me on the right path

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, it is always good to know. I Hope Docker guys are a going to create a more exhaustive documentation around these exit codes.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: If your use-case involves a deleted directory that's part of a volume, delete the docker volume, restart docker, then run `compose up` again

---

I was having the same issue, and it seemed related to one of my volumes.

I had the following definition in my `docker-compose` file:

```
  volumename:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: "${PWD}/data/some/dir"
```

I had deleted and re-created the `"${PWD}/data/some/dir"` directory, and then started getting `exit code 6` for the container that depended on the volume.

Things I tried:

- Restart docker
- Delete the volume (using the Docker Desktop UI) - this seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Exit code 6 is thrown when you are pointing to the wrong branch. Check if you are pointing to a valid branch or not: `docker-compose --verbose` should solve your issue.

Also, I would suggest you to check the volume section in your code once.